# yii2 :: Access the website using IP address instead of host name

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a website in yii2 in a shared hosting environment.

If  the website is accessed with hostname ie. http://hostname/web/site/login it is working fine.

But if the website is accessed with ip address ie http://192.168.2.2/web/site/login it is giving a 404 error.

But accessing with IP is working fine in local-computer. for example 
http://127.0.0.1/web/site/login

Any help is apreciated

Thanks

Riyas KP

Comment: are you sure the ip is correct ..?

Comment: yes...the ip was correct and i am to access other website in the same server using the url

Answer (score 0):

Because you are in a "shared hosting environment" the server has probably no way to know what website you want to see. For example, why would it redirect the requests to your website and not to another website on the same IP?

On your own pc it works because probably your website is the default website on it, that is why it works.

Anyway, just to figure out if the requests even gets to your application, is that an Yii2 404 page or is it a general one? I am sure that if you go to http://hostname/web/fsadasdfasdfasfd you will get a different 404 error than what you get when you go to http://192.168.2.2/web/site/login. That is because the requests never gets to Yii2, it will get handled by the server because it does not know where to route it.